# build error with boost spirit grammar (boost 1.43 and g++ 4.4.1)

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit

I'm having issues getting a small spirit/qi grammar to compile. The build stack trace is fugly enought to not make any sense to me (despite some assertion_failed i could notice in there but that didn't brought much information)

the input grammar header:

inputGrammar.h

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace sp = boost::spirit;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
using namespace boost::spirit::ascii;
//using namespace boost::spirit::arg_names;

namespace fusion = boost::fusion;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

using phoenix::at_c;
using phoenix::push_back;


template< typename Iterator , typename ExpressionAST >
struct InputGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, ExpressionAST(), space_type> {

    InputGrammar() : InputGrammar::base_type( block ) {
        tag = sp::lexeme[+(alpha)        [sp::_val += sp::_1]];//[+(char_ - '<')        [_val += _1]];

        block = sp::lit("block") [ at_c<0>(sp::_val) = sp::_1]
                >> "(" >> *instruction[ push_back( at_c<1>(sp::_val) , sp::_1 ) ]
                >> ")";

        command = tag   [ at_c<0>(sp::_val) = sp::_1]
                                >> "(" >> *instruction [ push_back( at_c<1>(sp::_val) , sp::_1 )]
                                >> ")";

        instruction = ( command | tag ) [sp::_val = sp::_1];
    }
    qi::rule< Iterator , std::string() , space_type > tag;
    qi::rule< Iterator , ExpressionAST() , space_type > block;
    qi::rule< Iterator , ExpressionAST() , space_type > function_def;
    qi::rule< Iterator , ExpressionAST() , space_type > command;
    qi::rule< Iterator , ExpressionAST() , space_type > instruction;
};
```

the test build program:
i seems the build fails at qi::phrase_parse, i am using boost 1.43 and g++ 4.4.1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//my grammar
#include <InputGrammar.h>

struct MockExpressionNode {
    std::string name;
    std::vector< MockExpressionNode > operands;

    typedef std::vector< MockExpressionNode >::iterator iterator;
    typedef std::vector< MockExpressionNode >::const_iterator const_iterator;

    iterator begin() { return operands.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return operands.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return operands.end(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return operands.end(); }

    bool is_leaf() const {
        return ( operands.begin() == operands.end() );
    }
};


BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    MockExpressionNode,
    (std::string, name)
    (std::vector<MockExpressionNode>, operands)
)

int const tabsize = 4;

void tab(int indent)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < indent; ++i)
        std::cout << ' ';
}

template< typename ExpressionNode >
struct ExpressionNodePrinter
{
    ExpressionNodePrinter(int indent = 0)
      : indent(indent)
    {
    }

    void operator()(ExpressionNode const& node) const {
        cout << " tag: " << node.name << endl;
        for (int i=0 ; i < node.operands.size() ; i++ ) {
            tab( indent ); cout << " arg "<<i<<": "; ExpressionNodePrinter(indent + 2)( node.operands[i]); cout << endl;
        }
    }

    int indent;
};

int test() {
 MockExpressionNode root;
    InputGrammar< string::const_iterator , MockExpressionNode > g();
    std::string litA = "litA";
    std::string litB = "litB";
    std::string litC = "litC";
    std::string litD = "litD";
    std::string litE = "litE";
    std::string litF = "litF";
    std::string source = litA+"( "+litB+" ,"+litC+" , "+ litD+" ( "+litE+", "+litF+" ) "+ " )";
    string::const_iterator iter = source.begin();
    string::const_iterator end = source.end();
    bool r = qi::phrase_parse( iter , end , g , root , space );
    ExpressionNodePrinter< MockExpressionNode > np;
    np( root );
};

int main() {
   test();
}
```

finally, the build error is the following:

```
/usr/bin/make -f nbproject/Makefile-linux_amd64_devel.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: se ingresa al directorio `/home/mineq/NetBeansProjects/InputParserTests'
/usr/bin/make  -f nbproject/Makefile-linux_amd64_devel.mk dist/linux_amd64_devel/GNU-Linux-x86/vpuinputparsertests
make[2]: se ingresa al directorio `/home/mineq/NetBeansProjects/InputParserTests'
mkdir -p build/linux_amd64_devel/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f build/linux_amd64_devel/GNU-Linux-x86/tests_main.o.d
g++ `llvm-config --cxxflags` `pkg-config --cflags unittest-cpp` `pkg-config --cflags boost-1.43` `pkg-config --cflags boost-coroutines`    -c -g -I../InputParser -MMD -MP -MF build/linux_amd64_devel/GNU-Linux-x86/tests_main.o.d -o build/linux_amd64_devel/GNU-Linux-x86/tests_main.o tests_main.cpp
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/auto.hpp:16,
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:15,
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from ../InputParser/InputGrammar.h:12,
                 from tests_main.cpp:14:
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp: In function ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, boost::spirit::qi::skip_flag::enum_type, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Expr = InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>(), Skipper = MockExpressionNode, Attr = const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>]’:
In file included from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/parse_auto.hpp:14,
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp:125:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Expr = InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>(), Skipper = MockExpressionNode, Attr = const boost::spirit::ascii::space_type]’
tests_main.cpp:206:   instantiated from here
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp:99: error: no matching function for call to ‘assertion_failed(mpl_::failed************ (boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, boost::spirit::qi::skip_flag::enum_type, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Expr = InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>(), Skipper = MockExpressionNode, Attr = const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>]::error_invalid_expression::************)(InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode> (*)()))’
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp:125:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Expr = InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>(), Skipper = MockExpressionNode, Attr = const boost::spirit::ascii::space_type]’
tests_main.cpp:206:   instantiated from here
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp:100: error: no matching function for call to ‘assertion_failed(mpl_::failed************ (boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, boost::spirit::qi::skip_flag::enum_type, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Expr = InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>(), Skipper = MockExpressionNode, Attr = const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>]::error_invalid_expression::************)(MockExpressionNode))’
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/proto/proto.hpp:12,
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/support/meta_compiler.hpp:17,
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/meta_compiler.hpp:14,
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/action/action.hpp:14,
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/action.hpp:14,
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:14,
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from ../InputParser/InputGrammar.h:12,
                 from tests_main.cpp:14:
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/proto/detail/expr0.hpp: At global scope:
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/proto/proto_fwd.hpp: In instantiation of ‘boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>()>, 0l>’:
In file included from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/proto/core.hpp:13,
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/utility/enable_if.hpp:59:   instantiated from ‘boost::disable_if<boost::proto::result_of::is_expr<boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>()>, 0l>, void>, void>’
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/support/meta_compiler.hpp:200:   instantiated from ‘boost::spirit::result_of::compile<boost::spirit::qi::domain, InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>(), boost::fusion::unused_type, void>’
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp:107:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, boost::spirit::qi::skip_flag::enum_type, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Expr = InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>(), Skipper = MockExpressionNode, Attr = const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>]’
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp:125:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Expr = InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>(), Skipper = MockExpressionNode, Attr = const boost::spirit::ascii::space_type]’
tests_main.cpp:206:   instantiated from here
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/proto/detail/expr0.hpp:64: error: field ‘boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>()>, 0l>::child0’ invalidly declared function type
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/auto.hpp:16,
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:15,
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from ../InputParser/InputGrammar.h:12,
                 from tests_main.cpp:14:
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp: In function ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, boost::spirit::qi::skip_flag::enum_type, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Expr = InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>(), Skipper = MockExpressionNode, Attr = const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>]’:
In file included from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/parse_auto.hpp:14,
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp:125:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Expr = InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>(), Skipper = MockExpressionNode, Attr = const boost::spirit::ascii::space_type]’
tests_main.cpp:206:   instantiated from here
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp:107: error: request for member ‘parse’ in ‘boost::spirit::compile [with Domain = boost::spirit::qi::domain, Expr = InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>()](((InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode> (&)())((InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode> (*)())expr)))’, which is of non-class type ‘InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>()’
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/auto.hpp:15,
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp:15,
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp:16,
                 from ../InputParser/InputGrammar.h:12,
                 from tests_main.cpp:14:
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/skip_over.hpp: In function ‘void boost::spirit::qi::skip_over(Iterator&, const Iterator&, const T&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, T = boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, boost::spirit::qi::skip_flag::enum_type, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Expr = InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>(), Skipper = MockExpressionNode, Attr = const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>]::skipper_type]’:
In file included from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/auto/auto.hpp:19,
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp:112:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, boost::spirit::qi::skip_flag::enum_type, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Expr = InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>(), Skipper = MockExpressionNode, Attr = const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>]’
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp:125:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(Iterator&, Iterator, const Expr&, const Skipper&, Attr&) [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Expr = InputGrammar<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode>(), Skipper = MockExpressionNode, Attr = const boost::spirit::ascii::space_type]’
tests_main.cpp:206:   instantiated from here
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/skip_over.hpp:27: error: ‘const struct MockExpressionNode’ has no member named ‘parse’
make[2]: *** [build/linux_amd64_devel/GNU-Linux-x86/tests_main.o] Error 1
make[2]: se sale del directorio `/home/mineq/NetBeansProjects/InputParserTests'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio `/home/mineq/NetBeansProjects/InputParserTests'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1m 48s)
```

Comment: No clue about spirit, but note that the declaration of of `g` in `test` is actually a function declaration. You need to omit the parens after `g`.

Comment: isnt supposed to be equivalent to the default constructor?

Comment: @lurscher: No, the C++ parser prefers a function declaration. It's not *always* equivalent.

Comment: @lurscher One thing: phrase_parse call should be `qi::phrase_parse(iter , end , g , space, root);`  The error messages are long, but read through top-down and its not hard to cypher them.

Comment: @academicRobot you are right that was it, but it is definitely hard to decypher what part of those errors is saying 'argument type mismatch'

Comment: @lursher You're right, it would be nice if it were more explicit.  Template errors can be pretty hairy in general, but spirit authors have worked to make them more informative: `error_invalid_expression::************)(MockExpressionNode)` is much better than `MockExpression has no such member foo`.  Takes some getting used to for sure.

Comment: @lurscher, It's never an object declaration. It's always a function declaration. You can't have an empty `()` initializer in variable declarations - those are reserved to denote an empty parameter type list for functions.

Comment: thanks everyone, removing the () and switching the root with the space argument did get me past the error i was having, but now i'm getting an even longer and more obfuscate error, but this one seems to be pointing to my grammar rule construction code. Please see the details at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042587/build-error-with-boost-spirit-grammar-boost-1-43-and-g-4-4-1-part-ii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute(s) always have to be passed as the last parameter(s) to the parse/phrase_parse functions. So you need to write:

```
bool r = qi::phrase_parse( iter , end , g , space, root );
```

Further, you can remove all semantic actions from your grammar if you add additional constructors to the ExpressionAST type:

```
template< typename Iterator , typename ExpressionAST > 
struct InputGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, ExpressionAST(), space_type> { 

    InputGrammar() : InputGrammar::base_type( block ) { 
        tag = sp::lexeme[+(alpha)]; 
        block = sp::lit("block") >> "(" >> *instruction >> ")"; 
        command = tag >> "(" >> *instruction >> ")"; 
        instruction = ( command | tag ); 
    } 
    qi::rule< Iterator , std::string() , space_type > tag; 
    qi::rule< Iterator , ExpressionAST() , space_type > block; 
    qi::rule< Iterator , ExpressionAST() , space_type > function_def; 
    qi::rule< Iterator , ExpressionAST() , space_type > command; 
    qi::rule< Iterator , ExpressionAST() , space_type > instruction; 
};
```

and

```
struct MockExpressionNode { 
    // ...
    MockExpressionNode() {}
    MockExpressionNode(std::string name) : name(name) {}
    // ...
};
```

But even then it won't compile because the MockExpressionNode data structure is self-recursive. This can be fixed by either storing a vector of pointers (which requires to changethe grammar) or by using [boost::recursive_wrapper](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.advanced).