# build error with boost spirit grammar (boost 1.43 and g++ 4.4.1) part II

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit

I'm having issues getting a small spirit/qi grammar to compile. i am using boost 1.43 and g++ 4.4.1.

the input grammar header:
the build error seems to be pointing to the definition of the 'instruction' rule, maybe it is the '[sp::_val = sp::_1]' that somehow brokes it but this is more or less based on what the spirit documentation tutorials are doing with the xml node parser

inputGrammar.h

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_fusion.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace sp = boost::spirit;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
using namespace boost::spirit::ascii;
//using namespace boost::spirit::arg_names;

namespace fusion = boost::fusion;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

using phoenix::at_c;
using phoenix::push_back;


template< typename Iterator , typename ExpressionAST >
struct InputGrammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, ExpressionAST(), space_type> {

    InputGrammar() : InputGrammar::base_type( block ) {
        tag = sp::lexeme[+(alpha)        [sp::_val += sp::_1]];//[+(char_ - '<')        [_val += _1]];

        block = sp::lit("block") [ at_c<0>(sp::_val) = sp::_1]
                >> "(" >> *instruction[ push_back( at_c<1>(sp::_val) , sp::_1 ) ]
                >> ")";

        command = tag   [ at_c<0>(sp::_val) = sp::_1]
                                >> "(" >> *instruction [ push_back( at_c<1>(sp::_val) , sp::_1 )]
                                >> ")";

        instruction = ( command | tag ) [sp::_val = sp::_1]; //build error seems to be happening here
    }
    qi::rule< Iterator , std::string() , space_type > tag;
    qi::rule< Iterator , ExpressionAST() , space_type > block;
    qi::rule< Iterator , ExpressionAST() , space_type > function_def;
    qi::rule< Iterator , ExpressionAST() , space_type > command;
    qi::rule< Iterator , ExpressionAST() , space_type > instruction;
};
```

the test build program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

//my grammar
#include <InputGrammar.h>

struct MockExpressionNode {
    std::string name;
    std::vector< MockExpressionNode > operands;

    typedef std::vector< MockExpressionNode >::iterator iterator;
    typedef std::vector< MockExpressionNode >::const_iterator const_iterator;

    iterator begin() { return operands.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return operands.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return operands.end(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return operands.end(); }

    bool is_leaf() const {
        return ( operands.begin() == operands.end() );
    }
};


BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    MockExpressionNode,
    (std::string, name)
    (std::vector<MockExpressionNode>, operands)
)

int const tabsize = 4;

void tab(int indent)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < indent; ++i)
        std::cout << ' ';
}

template< typename ExpressionNode >
struct ExpressionNodePrinter
{
    ExpressionNodePrinter(int indent = 0)
      : indent(indent)
    {
    }

    void operator()(ExpressionNode const& node) const {
        cout << " tag: " << node.name << endl;
        for (int i=0 ; i < node.operands.size() ; i++ ) {
            tab( indent ); cout << " arg "<<i<<": "; ExpressionNodePrinter(indent + 2)( node.operands[i]); cout << endl;
        }
    }

    int indent;
};

int test() {
 MockExpressionNode root;
    InputGrammar< string::const_iterator , MockExpressionNode > g;
    std::string litA = "litA";
    std::string litB = "litB";
    std::string litC = "litC";
    std::string litD = "litD";
    std::string litE = "litE";
    std::string litF = "litF";
    std::string source = litA+"( "+litB+" ,"+litC+" , "+ litD+" ( "+litE+", "+litF+" ) "+ " )";
    string::const_iterator iter = source.begin();
    string::const_iterator end = source.end();
    bool r = qi::phrase_parse( iter , end , g , space , root );
    ExpressionNodePrinter< MockExpressionNode > np;
    np( root );
};

int main() {
   test();
}
```

finally, the build error is the following:

(the full error trace is 20 times bigger than the allowed size for a stackoverflow question, so i posted the full version of it at http://codepad.org/Q74IVCUc)

```
/usr/bin/make -f nbproject/Makefile-linux_amd64_devel.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: se ingresa al directorio `/home/mineq/NetBeansProjects/InputParserTests'
/usr/bin/make  -f nbproject/Makefile-linux_amd64_devel.mk dist/linux_amd64_devel/GNU-Linux-x86/vpuinputparsertests
make[2]: se ingresa al directorio `/home/mineq/NetBeansProjects/InputParserTests'
mkdir -p build/linux_amd64_devel/GNU-Linux-x86
rm -f build/linux_amd64_devel/GNU-Linux-x86/tests_main.o.d
g++ `llvm-config --cxxflags` `pkg-config --cflags unittest-cpp` `pkg-config --cflags boost-1.43` `pkg-config --cflags boost-coroutines`    -c -g -I../InputParser -MMD -MP -MF build/linux_amd64_devel/GNU-Linux-x86/tests_main.o.d -o build/linux_amd64_devel/GNU-Linux-x86/tests_main.o tests_main.cpp
                 from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp:11,
                 from ../InputParser/InputGrammar.h:14,
                 from tests_main.cpp:14:
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/phoenix/operator/self.hpp: In instantiation of ‘const int boost::phoenix::result_of_assign<MockExpressionNode&, boost::variant<MockExpressionNode, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>&>::size’:
In file included from /home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/phoenix/operator.hpp:16,
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/phoenix/operator/self.hpp:27:   instantiated from ‘const int boost::phoenix::result_of_assign<MockExpressionNode&, boost::variant<MockExpressionNode, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>&>::index’
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/phoenix/operator/self.hpp:27:   instantiated from ‘boost::phoenix::result_of_assign<MockExpressionNode&, boost::variant<MockExpressionNode, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>&>’
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/mpl/eval_if.hpp:38:   instantiated from ‘boost::mpl::eval_if<boost::mpl::or_<boost::phoenix::is_actor<MockExpressionNode&>, boost::phoenix::is_actor<boost::variant<MockExpressionNode, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>&>, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false>, mpl_::bool_<false> >, boost::phoenix::re_curry<boost::phoenix::assign_eval, MockExpressionNode&, boost::variant<MockExpressionNode, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>&, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_>, boost::phoenix::result_of_assign<MockExpressionNode&, boost::variant<MockExpressionNode, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>&> >’
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/phoenix/operator/self.hpp:69:   instantiated from ‘boost::phoenix::assign_eval::result<boost::phoenix::basic_environment<boost::fusion::vector1<boost::variant<MockExpressionNode, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>&>, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<MockExpressionNode&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >, bool, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_>, boost::spirit::attribute<0>, boost::spirit::argument<0> >’
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/phoenix/core/detail/composite_eval.hpp:89:   instantiated from ‘boost::phoenix::detail::composite_eval<2>::result<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::assign_eval, boost::fusion::vector<boost::spirit::attribute<0>, boost::spirit::argument<0>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> >, boost::phoenix::basic_environment<boost::fusion::vector1<boost::variant<MockExpressionNode, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>&>, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<MockExpressionNode&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >, bool, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> >’
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/phoenix/core/composite.hpp:61:   instantiated from ‘boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::assign_eval, boost::fusion::vector<boost::spirit::attribute<0>, boost::spirit::argument<0>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> >::result<boost::phoenix::basic_environment<boost::fusion::vector1<boost::variant<MockExpressionNode, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>&>, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<MockExpressionNode&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >, bool, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> >’
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/phoenix/core/actor.hpp:56:   instantiated from ‘boost::phoenix::eval_result<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::assign_eval, boost::fusion::vector<boost::spirit::attribute<0>, boost::spirit::argument<0>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> >, boost::phoenix::basic_environment<boost::fusion::vector1<boost::variant<MockExpressionNode, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>&>, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<MockExpressionNode&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >, bool, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> >’
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/phoenix/core/actor.hpp:65:   instantiated from ‘boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::assign_eval, boost::fusion::vector<boost::spirit::attribute<0>, boost::spirit::argument<0>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> > >::result<boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::assign_eval, boost::fusion::vector<boost::spirit::attribute<0>, boost::spirit::argument<0>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> > >(boost::fusion::vector1<boost::variant<MockExpressionNode, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>&>&, boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<MockExpressionNode&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >&, bool&)>’
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/support/action_dispatch.hpp:44:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::traits::action_dispatch<Component>::operator()(const boost::phoenix::actor<Eval>&, Attribute&, Context&) [with Eval = boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::assign_eval, boost::fusion::vector<boost::spirit::attribute<0>, boost::spirit::argument<0>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> >, Attribute = boost::variant<MockExpressionNode, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_, boost::detail::variant::void_>, Context = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<MockExpressionNode&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >, Component = boost::spirit::qi::alternative<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::fusion::unused_type> >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::string(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::fusion::unused_type> >, boost::fusion::nil> > >]’
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/action/action.hpp:62:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::action<Subject, Action>::parse(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&, Attribute&) const [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Context = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<MockExpressionNode&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, Attribute = const boost::fusion::unused_type, Subject = boost::spirit::qi::alternative<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::fusion::unused_type> >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::string(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::fusion::unused_type> >, boost::fusion::nil> > >, Action = boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::assign_eval, boost::fusion::vector<boost::spirit::attribute<0>, boost::spirit::argument<0>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> > >]’
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/detail/parser_binder.hpp:33:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<Parser, Auto>::call(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&, mpl_::true_) const [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, Context = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<MockExpressionNode&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >, Parser = boost::spirit::qi::action<boost::spirit::qi::alternative<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::fusion::unused_type> >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::string(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::fusion::unused_type> >, boost::fusion::nil> > >, boost::phoenix::actor<boost::phoenix::composite<boost::phoenix::assign_eval, boost::fusion::vector<boost::spirit::attribute<0>, boost::spirit::argument<0>, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_> > > >, Auto = mpl_::bool_<false>]’
/home/mineq/third_party/boost_1_43_0/boost/spirit/home/qi/nonterminal/detail/parser_binder.hpp:53:   instantiated from ‘bool boost::spirit::qi::detail::parser_binder<Parser, Auto>::operator()(Iterator&, const Iterator&, Context&, const Skipper&) const [with Iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, Skipper = boost::spirit::qi::char_class<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, Context = boost::spirit::context<boost::fusion::cons<MockExpressionNode&, boost::fusion::nil>, boost::fusion::vector0<void> >, Parser = boost::spirit::qi::action<boost::spirit::qi::alternative<boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, MockExpressionNode(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::fusion::unused_type> >, boost::fusion::cons<boost::spirit::qi::reference<const boost::spirit::qi::rule<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::string(), boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tag::terminal, boost::proto::argsns_::term<boost::spirit::tag::char_code<boost::spirit::tag::space, boost::spirit::char_encoding::ascii> >, 0l>, boost::fusion::unused_type, boost::fusion::unused_type> >, boost::fusion::nil> > >, 
 ...
```

... more errors but i had to truncate to fit the 30k limit

```
make[2]: *** [build/linux_amd64_devel/GNU-Linux-x86/tests_main.o] Error 1
make[2]: se sale del directorio `/home/mineq/NetBeansProjects/InputParserTests'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: se sale del directorio `/home/mineq/NetBeansProjects/InputParserTests'
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2m 13s)
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the error message?  It looks more the length of a Tolstoy novel.

Comment: definitely it makes the ulysses of joyce to seem such a light and joyful reading

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your [error message](http://codepad.org/Q74IVCUc) tells you that you want to assign a `variant<MockExpressionNode, basic_string>` to a `MockExpressionNode`

The relevant lines are 33 and 34;

```
[...] error: no match for ‘operator=’ [...] boost::variant<MockExpressionNode, std::basic_string [...]
[...] candidates are: MockExpressionNode& MockExpressionNode::operator=(const MockExpressionNode&) [...]
```

To understand why this happens we have to look at the definitions. From the definition of a [Qi rule](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/nonterminal/rule.html), the signature of the returned value is defined by a template parameter. Hence

```
qi::rule< Iterator , ExpressionAST() , space_type > command;
```

means that the returned type of a `command` will be an `ExpressionAST` (i.e. a `MockExpressionNode` in your case). Similarly

```
qi::rule< Iterator , std::string() , space_type > tag;
```

means that `tag` will be of type `string`. Combining this with `instruction = (command | tag)` means that an `instruction` is either a `string` or a `MockExpressionNode`. This is internally stored as a `variant<MockExpressionNode, string>`. Finally,

```
qi::rule< Iterator , ExpressionAST() , space_type > instruction;
```

implies that the returned type of `instruction` is again an `ExpressionAST` (i.e. a `MockExpressionNode`). This requires the failing assignment from the `variant` held internally to a `MockExpressionNode`.

To sum up, you have to provide types in your `qi::rule`s that somewhat "match" the types implied by your grammar in the sense that assignment is possible. Despite all the Boost.Spirit magic, C++ is still a statically typed language after all. For the issue at hand, you either have to supply a fitting `operator=`, or you have to assign the results of the different rules to different types that support implicit conversion. BTW, you have similar type issues for `block` and `command` at the moment. Take a careful look at the [mini_xml example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/mini_xml1.cpp) in the documentation: how to define types for a recursive structure and how different rules assign to different types depending on the defined grammar (especially rules `xml` and `node`).

Comment: thanks! that explanation at the end help me clarify what is really going on